# url a partir da raíz do site

Tags: php, javascript, html, path

Boa tarde, gostava que me esclarecessem-se uma dúvida que tenho à já algum tempo em PHP.

Por exemplo, no caso, a seguir tenho o sistema de tradução do site, mas ele só funciona para o directorio em que ele está, ou seja ele só funciona se for incluído em paginas num directorio, se for num subdirectorio, teria de fazer um novo ficheiro sistema de tradução com os links a começar em `../`.

Existe alguma solução melhor para resolver esse problema, do género um `link raiz/lang/pt.php` que funcionasse em qualquer pagina em qualquer diretório. Já experimentei `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` mas não me parece funcionar direito no local host, traz-me a localização fo ficheiro (c:/xaamp/htdocs/).

```
<?php
//Detecao se não existir cookie
if(!isset($_COOKIE["lang"])){
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang){

    case "pt":
        //echo "PAGE PT";
        $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
        setcookie("lang", "pt", $expire);
        $_COOKIE["lang"] = "pt";
        break;

    case "en":
        //echo "PAGE EN";
        $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
        setcookie("lang", "en", $expire);
        $_COOKIE["lang"] = "en";
        break;

    default:
        //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
        $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
        setcookie("lang", "en", $expire);
        $_COOKIE["lang"] = "en";
        break;
}
}
//Alteração linguagem por link

if(isset($_GET["lang"])){
    $lang = $_GET["lang"];
    switch ($lang){

        case "pt":
             //echo "PAGE PT";
            $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
            setcookie("lang", "pt", $expire);
            $_COOKIE["lang"] = "pt";
             break;

        case "en":
            //echo "PAGE EN";
            $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
            setcookie("lang", "en", $expire);
            $_COOKIE["lang"] = "en";
             break;

        default:
            //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
            $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
            setcookie("lang", "en", $expire);
            $_COOKIE["lang"] = "en";
            break;
}
}


// No caso de existir cookie

$lang = $_COOKIE["lang"];

switch ($lang){

    case "pt":
        //echo "PAGE PT";
        //include
        require_once("lang/pt.php");
        break;

    case "en":
        //echo "PAGE EN";
        //include
        require_once("lang/en.php");
        break;

    default:
        //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
        //include
        require_once("lang/en.php");
        break;
}
?>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Se o problema é só encontrar o nome do host:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]
```

Ao iniciar um link com "/" o navegador, automaticamente usa o host atual. Exemplo: Estando na página `http://www.exemplo.com/pagina1.php`, o link:

```
<a href="/dir/minhapagina.php">link</a>
```

levará à página `http://www.exemplo.com/dir/minhapagina.php`, exceto se a própria página configurar o navegador para tratar de forma diferente.

Outras variáveis com informações úteis podem ser encontradas com o comando `phpinfo();` em uma página php.